# Warning Messages: NA's introduced by coercion ; Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I'm working on a project where I need to create a `direction` variable based on the previous days stock price - "Up" if higher than the previous day, "Down" otherwise. The code I have is as follows.

```
price.diff <- ave(return_adj$SPY.Adjusted, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x)))

Warning message:
In NextMethod(.Generic) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

direction <- ifelse(price.diff > 0, "Up", "Down")

return_adj$Direction <- direction

Warning message:
In merge.xts(..., all = all, fill = fill, suffixes = suffixes) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

return_adj$Direction
```

It was working yesterday and now it's not so I really don't understand enough how to fix this problem. Any help/education would be appreciated.

Edit***

```
dput(return_adj$SPY.Adjusted) returns
    structure(c(-0.00224573007143558, 0.00141229206196769, 0.00530969739851805, 
    -0.00132097826319999), index = structure(c(1363046400, 1363132800, 
    1363219200, 1363305600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1616254627.41846, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), ret_type = "log", coredata_content = "logReturn", na.action = structure(1L, class = "omit", index = 1362960000), .Dim = c(4L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "SPY.Adjusted"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! in order to answer your question, you need to show us your data, paste the output of `dput(return_adj$SPY.Adjusted)` so we can run code with. And why did you used `ave` instead of just `price.diff <- c(0, diff(return_adj$SPY.Adjusted))`?

Comment: I was told the ave() function would be useful because you can apply any function FUN on X to get an output of same length as X...

Comment: I imported my data from yahoo finance and the code is too long to include here but I updated the original post to include the output.

Answer (score 1):

As it's quite unclear from the post what variable you are concerned with here's a tentative shot:

Supposing this is your data:

```
df <- structure(c(-0.00224573007143558, 0.00141229206196769, 0.00530969739851805, -0.00132097826319999), index = structure(c(1363046400, 1363132800, 1363219200, 1363305600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1616254627.41846, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), ret_type = "log", coredata_content = "logReturn", na.action = structure(1L, class = "omit", index = 1362960000), .Dim = c(4L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "SPY.Adjusted"))
```

`str` reveals that the structure is very convoluted:

```
str(df)
‘zoo’ series from 1363046400 to 1363305600
  Data: num [1:4, 1] -0.00225 0.00141 0.00531 -0.00132
 - attr(*, "src")= chr "yahoo"
 - attr(*, "updated")= POSIXct[1:1], format: "2021-03-20 16:37:07"
 - attr(*, "ret_type")= chr "log"
 - attr(*, "coredata_content")= chr "logReturn"
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' int 1
  ..- attr(*, "index")= num 1.36e+09
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "SPY.Adjusted"
  Index:  num [1:4] 1.36e+09 1.36e+09 1.36e+09 1.36e+09
 - attr(*, "tzone")= chr "UTC"
 - attr(*, "tclass")= chr "Date"
```

To bring some order into it, convert if to a dataframe:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

Now you can use `ifelse` to assign your labels:

```
df$direction <- ifelse(df$SPY.Adjusted > 0, "Up", "Down")
```

The result is this:

```
df
           SPY.Adjusted direction
1363046400 -0.002245730      Down
1363132800  0.001412292        Up
1363219200  0.005309697        Up
1363305600 -0.001320978      Down
```

Comment: Listen buddy, I very clearly stated that I was looking at the direction variable so I could do without the condescension.

Comment: condescension, which condescension?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a self contained example.  Use `na.omit(SPYd)` if you don't want the NA.  Note that xts objects represent the data as a matrix and a matrix can't represent numeric and character data in the same object so we used +1 and -1 instead of Up and Down.  We could alternately use `sign(returns)` if you wanted +1, 0 and -1 where 0 is flat.

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("SPY")
returns <- dailyReturn(Ad(SPY), leading = FALSE)
direction <- setNames(ifelse(returns > 0, +1, -1), "direction")
SPYd <- cbind(Ad(SPY), returns, direction)
head(SPYd)
```

giving this xts object:

```
           SPY.Adjusted daily.returns direction
2007-01-03     106.1306            NA        NA
2007-01-04     106.3558  0.0021219603         1
2007-01-05     105.5075 -0.0079763178        -1
2007-01-08     105.9955  0.0046253956         1
2007-01-09     105.9054 -0.0008502057        -1
2007-01-10     106.2583  0.0033317656         1
```